# With MPI programs, do all processes get data from user input?

Tags: c++, mpi

What I'm asking is if I have something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) //<---input from command line
{
```

Do I need to use MPI_Bcast in order to send that data to all of the processes, or do all of the processes get the command line input data anyway?

Comment: See [here](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-11-html/node151.html)

Comment: @talonmies Umm, so does that mean that if I use MPI_Init(&argc,&argv), they will be passed without the broadcast?

Comment: exactly where is "server" and "client side" mentioned in the edit. I changed "cores" to "processes" because that is the correct term. If a "noob" (your term not mine) looks at any documentation or tutorial on any version of MPI, all they will see is process. The word core will never appear. MPI is an interprocess message passing protocol for distributed memory computing. There is no concept of cores anywhere. IMHO the edit makes the question and answer much easier to find by search. I am rolling back you edit. If you dont like it, take it to meta.

Comment: @talonmies I'm sorry I put that in the wrong post. Although I can't say I fully agree with what you said either, that change doesn't bother me much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use MPI_Init(&argc,&argv) this solves you problem :)

No need to BCast anything ;)

Comment: Note that if you don't need to pass argc and argv, you still need to call MPI_Init. You can just pass NULL as argument.

Answer (score 2):

Passing the full command line to all MPI processes is part of the initial launch mechanism. This is intentionally omitted from the MPI standard, but most MPI implementations do the Right Thing (tm) and actually pass all command line arguments to all processes in the MPI job. It is even possible to have different command line arguments passed to different ranks and even several different executables started in a single MPI job.

For example, the following command will start 10 copies of the same executable `program` and pass each of them the same command line arguments `arg1` and `arg2`:

```
$ mpiexec -n 10 program arg1 arg2
```

The following command will start 10 copies of `program` and pass `arg1` to the first five processes (ranks 0 to 4) and `arg2` to the next five processes (ranks 5 to 9):

```
$ mpiexec -n 5 program arg1 : -n 5 program arg2
```

The following command will start 5 copies of `program1` with arguments `arg1` and 5 copies of `program2` with arguments `arg2`:

```
$ mpiexec -n 5 program1 arg1 : -n 5 program2 arg2
```

Calling `MPI_Init()` has nothing to do with the mechanism by which the MPI processes are started. Passing `argc` and `argv` to `MPI_Init` was required in the very old MPI-1 specification since many MPI implementations used additional command line arguments in order to bootstrap the MPI job. Yet this requirement was somehow artificial since the Fortran bindings didn't have that arguments (in Fortran 77 there is no standard way to obtain the command line arguments) and somehow they were properly implemented. Therefore MPI-2 removed this requirement and allows for `NULL`s to be passed instead so that it is possible to write parallel libraries that in general have no access to the command line arguments. Therefore most MPI implementations switched to providing all the necessary bootstrap information through environment variables or other OS-specific mechanisms.